# Keeping track of the last time a user took an action

Tags: ios, time, datastore

I have an app which allows users to redeem voucher codes, however I want to limit it so they can only claim one every 30 minutes.

So I somehow need to store the time they last redeemed a voucher, and if they try to redeem another, the app would check the last time and only give them a new voucher if the last one was over half an hour ago.

Would I store data in user prefs or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Storing a timestamp of when the last voucher was redeemed in `NSUserDefaults` is probably fine for a simple solution.

But how secure do you need this to be? As a general rule, and especially if this needs to be strictly enforced for financial reasons, never trust the client.  Meaning that you should have a server to verify the codes, and enforce usage restrictions.

Comment: Security isn't a main issue, the client won't have much gain from cheating